# Django Converts a block content into all uppercase

Tags: django

Just starting to play around with Django and I'm trying to make the content of a block in all uppercase

**my base.html template**

```
{% block page-title %}{{ "test123"|upper }}{% endblock %}
```

and it will output perfectly with TEST123

I would like to make it always uppercase and not having to apply the upper tag each time I want to overwrite it.

**For example in my contact.html**

```
{% block page-title %}Contact us{% endblock %}
```

I want to keep it as DRY as possible and not having to type {{ "Contact us"|upper }} .

I've tried `{{ {% block page-title %}{% endblock %}|upper }}` but I get a `TemplateSyntaxError`

Comment: Would css be better for this task? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: `{{ {% block page-title %}{% endblock %}|upper }}` you tried something most people fear to do. great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `{% filter %}` tag to apply a filter to a whole bunch of variables.

```
{% filter upper %}
   A whole bunch of {{ text }} and {{ variables }}
{% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 4):

While not addressing your question with Python there is a simple CSS approach ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)):

```
text-transform: uppercase
```